# Remove space from actionBar in Android Kotlin fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

I use fragments for the bottom navigation.

I have defined a theme with the parent Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge.

It works fine on *activities*, but the **fragments** show a gap.

This is the BottomNavigationActivity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
    val user = userFromIntent
    initGoogleSignInClient()

    binding = ActivityBottomNavigationMenuBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_activities, R.id.navigation_more
        )
    )
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

}
```

An excerpt from MoreFragment.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    fragmentMoreBinding = FragmentMoreBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Any ideas? I have tried something similar to this:

`((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize on the XML I have the nav_host_fragment_activity_main and it worked!